# Pandas, why does string matching stops at the first letter

Tags: python, pandas, string, string-matching

I have a series that contains companies and they're stocks names joined:

```
                             stock

0                            AAPLApple
1                       AMZNAmazon.com
2                           FBFacebook
3                          NFLXNetflix
4                            INTCIntel
5                            TSLATesla
6                  MUMicron Technology
7                        MSFTMicrosoft
8                           NVDANVIDIA
9                    CSCOCisco Systems
11             LULULululemon Athletica
12                            EBAYeBay
13                        AVGOBroadcom
14                        QCOMQUALCOMM
15                 GILDGilead Sciences
16                  WDCWestern Digital
17                       GOOGLAlphabet
18                          BIIBBiogen
19                        GOOGAlphabet
20                URBNUrban Outfitters
21                          NTAPNetApp
22                          AABAAltaba
23                       SBUXStarbucks
24                         CELGCelgene
25                          SPLKSplunk
26                COSTCostco Wholesale
27           AMDAdvanced Micro Devices
28                          PYPLPaypal
29       REGNRegeneron Pharmaceuticals
30               AMATApplied Materials
                    ...               
Name: stock, Length: 243, dtype: object
```

I also have a list of the stocks symbols to match against:

```
['ETSY',
 'COUP',
 'TSLA',
 'CRWD',
 'ROKU',
 'A',
 'AAL',
 'AAP',
 'AAPL',
 'ABBV',
 'AEP',
 'AES',
 'AFL',
 'HUBS',
 'AIG',
 'AIV',
 'AIZ',
 'AJG',
 'AKAM',
 'ALB',
 'ALGN',
 'ALK',
 'ALL',
 'ALLE',
 'ALXN',
 'AMAT',
 'AMCR',
 'AMD',
 'AME',
 'AMGN',
 'AMP',
 'AMT',
 'AMZN',
...]
```

I want to match to strip every name in the stock column of the companies full name and leave only the symbol, if the symbol is not found then drop the row.
my code so far:

```py
def clean_name(name):
    companies = list(COMPANIES.keys())
    for company in companies:
        if company in name:
            return company
        return None
def sort_df():
    df[STOCK] = df[STOCK].apply(lambda x: clean_name(x))
    df = df.dropna()
    return df
```

the problem is that every matching of strings returns only one letter in most cases.

so the output is:

```
0         A
1         A
2         F
3         F
4         C
5      TSLA
6        MU
7         F
8         A
9         C
11        A
12        A
13        A
14        A
15        D
16        C
17        A
18     BIIB
19        A
20        O
21        A
22        A
23     SBUX
24        C
25     SPLK
26        C
27        A
28        L
29       RE
30        A
...
```

Comment: check list of stock symbole i think there is single character exits like 'A','F' etc that is why its returning single character, also other thing is return None should be out of for loop so, your loop is iterating once only not for all list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is reverse sorting by length for match first longest company names:

```
def clean_name(name):
    companies = list(COMPANIES.keys())
    for company in sorted(companies, key=len, reverse=True):
        if company in name:
            return company
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this would be to compile a regex string with the stock symbols, and run a match against the `stock` column in the DataFrame.

For example:

```
import re

# Build regex string.
exp_s = '|'.join('^{}'.format(i) for i in sorted(s, key=len, reverse=True))
exp = re.compile('({})'.format(exp_s))

# Match symbols using regex.
df['stock'].str.extract(exp).dropna()
```

Where:

```
# Stock symbols list.
s = ['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'FB', 'NFLX', ...]
```

Output:

```
0    AAPL
1    AMZN
2      FB
3    NFLX
...
26    AMD
27   PYPL
28   REGN
29   AMAT
```